# Unable to create a function with the same name as a static function

Tags: php, static-methods, instance-methods

When I try to create an instance function with the same name as a static function on that class, I get the following error message:

```
 Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Module::get_config() in [path]/static-redeclare.php on line 32
```

The full code I used for this test can be found here: https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/ccaebe6d660a7248ca9e

This type of error does not appear in other languages such as Action Script 3 and Java. Am I declaring either function incorrectly, or is PHP just "special" like that, and doesn't like repeated function names, even if they are in different scopes?

If it is the latter, is there a logical reason for PHP preventing static and instance function name collisions, or was it decided on a whim by the authors of the PHP language?

Comment: Relevant bug report - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40837

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is just special like that (and in many other ways too).

Considering that historically PHP has had no problem letting you call instance methods with static notation and vice versa, the reasons for the decision should best be left undisturbed.

<sub>I suppose it was done in the friendly PHP spirit of "I can kind of assume that the user probably wants to do X and doesn't know the difference from the Y they asked for, but let's not be judging. Just do X".</sub>